# Mapping a magnitude spectrum with linear frequency resolution

Tags: fourier-transform, python

For an Music Analysis Project I'm doing, I want to transform a song like it is done in this paper by K. Seyerlehner et al. http://dafx10.iem.at/proceedings/papers/SeyerlehnerWidmerPohle_DAFx10_P31.pdf

I'm totally new to Signal Processing, so I tried to look up everything but I'm stuck at the part, where I have to ***map the magnitude spectrum with linear frequency resolution.***

How exactly do I have to do that?

[image]

That's how far I've come:

```
import librosa
import numpy as np

# Load the audio file
y, sr = librosa.load('Music/song.wav', sr=22050)

# Compute Short-Time Fourier Transform (STFT) using a Hanning window, with window size 2048 samples and hop size 512 samples
n_fft = 2048
hop_length = 512
win_length = n_fft
window = 'hann'
stft = librosa.stft(y, n_fft=n_fft, hop_length=hop_length, win_length=win_length, window=window)

# Compute magnitude spectrum |X(f)|
magnitude_spectrum = np.abs(stft)

# Compute the Cent scale using the given equation 2

cent_scale = 1200 * np.log2(magnitude_spectrum / 440.0 * np.power(2.0, (-19.0 / 4)))
```

Maybe you have an idea on how to accomplish this task.

Comment: You were smart not to code that last part of $(2)$ directly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frequency axis is mapped as the OP has done. Every new frequency in the index `cent_scale` corresponds the the magnitude in `magnitude_spectrum` and at this point can be plotted on a loglog scale such as

```
plt.loglog(cent_scale, magnitude_spectrum)
```

or as typical in dB as

```
plt.semilogx(cent_scale, 20*np.log10(magnitude_spectrum))
```

The author is remapping the frequency axis using equation 2. As returned by the STFT used, the frequency axis is linearly spaced as $N=2048$ samples for $k=0$ to $N-1$, with $k=0$ corresponding to DC and $N$ corresponding to the sampling rate of 22 KHz. (So $k=1$ corresponds to the frequency $22e3/2048 \approx 10.742$ Hz, and is spaced linearly thereafter as we index through $k$. I believe this is what the author intended when saying "linear frequency resolution". The frequency resolution is set by the FFT block size and window used, but the frequency axis is linearly spaced. I would refer to this as a linearly spaced frequency with constant frequency resolution (not linear frequency resolution).

Regardless, given the frequencies linearly spaced as given above, each with their magnitude and phase as given by the STFT, each frequency is mapped to a logarithmically spaced frequency axis using equation 2. However unlike the actual Constant-Q transform (CQT) where the result is a bank of filters logarithmically spaced in frequency with constant Q, where Q is a ratio of center frequency to bandwidth; the operations done here are changing power measured at one frequency to appear as if they were measured at a different frequency (incorrectly).  For example, if we had a single tone at 8 KHz, the result of the author's mapping would make this tone appear that it is at:

$$1200\log_2(8000/(440\times 2^{\frac{-19}{4}})\approx 10.721 \text{ KHz}$$

When the signal is spread out over multiple bands, the results would be similar enough to the CQT in many cases, which I assume for the author’s intended application this resulted in a reasonable match. However I caution its wider applicability.

Comment: So basically the code is completed except the 3rd equation?

Comment: @Rocket yes, and then if you want to plot the response, with the two you can plot freq vs magnitude in dB where the frequency axis is plotted on a log scale as I demonstrated using “semilogx”